# How to copy custom texts into clipboard when click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input, and would like to make have a copy link next to its label.

[image]

When I click copy I want to not only copy the input value, but I would like to prepend more texts.

`http://www.test.com?code=` + `input value`

How do I do that?

```
//copy text 
function getLink(id) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

With this code above, only copy the value.

Comment: js and browsers have many anti-hacking features, and I would not be surprised to see the feature that you cannot sneakily add random invisible content to the clipboard

Comment: ah I see.. so I have to create a hidden input with the correct value then copy it over. I get it.

Comment: A hidden input is not suitable, the copy command requires the element being visible, though it must be visible only at the time the command is executed. You can do this with your existing code as well. Just store the value of the text input, replace the value in the input with your own value, select and copy, and restore the saved value. A user won't see any of this happening, as the page is next rendered after all the JS has been executed.

Comment: I see... so I can append a tmp input, and remove it back

Comment: Yes, that's also possible, but what I described above, you can do with the existing input element as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the value in the current input element, and then restore it to the original value after copied the edited value. Something like this:

```js
function getLink(e) {
  const copyPad = e.target.previousElementSibling,
    storedValue = copyPad.value,
    copyValue = 'http://www.test.com?code=' + storedValue;
  copyPad.value = copyValue;
  copyPad.select();
  copyPad.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("Copied the text: " + copyPad.value);
  copyPad.value = storedValue;
}

const but = document.querySelector('#copyLink');
but.addEventListener('click', getLink);
```

```html
<input><button id="copyLink">Copy</button>
<input> Paste here to check
```

A user can't see changes to the input element, because the page is not rendered before all the JS has been executed.